# Is there a better sync application for Windows than HTCSync?

Tags: htc-desire, sync, htc-sync-3.0

I'm running HTCSync 3.0.5422 on Windows 7 Ultimate but I find it just a bit unreliable. One one PC, sometimes the application doesn't see my HTC Desire (bought as an unlocked SIM free unit) and on another computer it just won't connect/sync at all.

Is there an alternative?

Comment: What are you actually using it to sync? Are you syncing files to and from the SD card, or syncing Outlook Mail.Contacts/Calendar? Or something esle? Do you need to sync with a PC, or would syncing to the web be better?

Comment: I'm syncing files (mp3's, photos etc), my outlook contacts and calendar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given android phones just run as USB drive mode for syncing:

Just for music:

- [DoubleTwist](http://www.doubletwist.com/)
- [Media Monkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/)

All Media:

- [WinAmp](http://www.winamp.com/)*

Will also sync outlook contacts, files etc.

- [Missing Sync for Android](http://www.markspace.com/products/android/missing-sync-android.html)*

*Syncs over Wi-fi

Comment: Thanks Gus...missing sync looks like the tool I'm after.

Comment: h/t to @mlevit for pointing out WinAmp in http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/321/

Comment: Missing Sync is not free. Not only is it not free, you can't even try the damn thing. You have to buy it and then try it. The price is no big deal (about 30 USD) but not being able to test the software to see if it can solve [my problem](http://superuser.com/questions/599815/why-do-i-get-the-error-no-outlook-profiles-were-found-in-htc-sync/599865#599865) means I refuse to buy it. Otherwise I would probably buy it if I could see that it works with my phone and Outlook. It really seems like a good piece of software.